# Canonical way to sign (and verify) an ELF file?

Tags: linux, code-signing, digital-signature, elf

I would like to sign ELF files, preferably with a PGP key and later be able to verify the signature. Failing that I'll also go with a Authenticode or SSL certificate for signing if that makes more sense. Existing options, such as [signelf](http://sourceforge.net/projects/signelf/), seem to be only available under copyleft licenses (even if it's the LGPL, but it imposes restrictions that prevent me from using it) or old/unmaintained.

What options do I have that can be used *in a proprietary program*?

Note: we can limit the scope of the question to Linux even though ELF isn't particular to Linux.

Even if there is no ready to use program and/or library under a liberal (non-copyleft) FLOSS license, I would appreciate pointers to standardization documents in case some kind of de-facto standard has emerged. I'm not aware of one, but then that's the reason I ask.

---

From what I see all distros seem to rely on signing the *packages* and verify these. That's fine in general but I would like to take it a step further.

Comment: did you check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732927/signed-executables-under-linux ?