# How do I sign the installed executable of a compiled matlab program?

Tags: matlab, sign, matlab-deployment, matlab-compiler

I have a program, written in MATLAB 2014b, that is compiled using Matlab Compiler Runtime and distributed as an executable: blah.exe.

I know it is possible to sign this executable (with a certificate I provide), but what if I wanted to sign the executable post-installation? Is this possible, and how would I do it?

Perhaps the signing carries over? Am I totally misunderstanding this?

EDIT: This is being done on Windows, for Windows users.

Comment: Signing an executable? Is this something that happens in a specific OS? Would be good to include that info in your question.

Comment: as far as I am aware this practice is common across all OSs but I am specifically concerned with Windows here.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be a thing on Linux. Apparently they tried, but abandoned the concept because it is not useful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9527322/7328782

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to a post on the MATLAB website, it isn't possible directly through the MATLAB compiler but can be done afterwards with signtool.exe which is provided with Visual Studio.

https://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/339976-matlab-compiler-how-do-i-sign-an-app-with-a-certificate-i-supply

Comment: I am aware of this and don't think it answers my questions completely. I want to sign the installed application and not the installer. It is possible to sign the installer using a third party application but will the installed application also be signed? or not?