# Is there an ELF equivelant of PE Original Filename

Tags: x86, elf, portable-executable

On Windows, PE files (executable files) have a property "Original Filename", which is the filename when the executable was built. For signed files, this means you can't change "svchost.exe" to "innocent.exe" without leaving a trail, for example.

Is there a similar property for ELF binaries?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not aware of any standard section that would store the original filename as created by the linker.

However, adding your own section to an ELF is perfectly fine. You can then sign the ELF with `elfsign` which by default covers the ELF sections.

This is a PKI system, so you then need a chain of trust to verify that signature.

Windows is probably using a CA rooted at Microsoft for their [Authenticode mechanism](https://download.microsoft.com/download/9/c/5/9c5b2167-8017-4bae-9fde-d599bac8184a/Authenticode_PE.docx) and hence can tell you if a PE has a valid signature (valid here means "with a key signed by Microsoft", you still don't know if *ACME inc.* is really *ACME inc.*).

Under Linux you have to give `elfverify` your trusted CA because there is no single entity behind Linux.

So you can just add a custom section and sign the elf. If you set the convention with any parties of yours that should do it.

---

**Note** that while Authenticode is used by Windows (I don't know if by the user-mode loader or in the kernel) to restrict the execution of binaries, `elfsign` doesn't do anything of that. It just sign ELFs.

There is a patch for checking the ELF signature, I'm not sure if it is in the tree. [But it can check ELFs signed with `signelf`](https://lwn.net/Articles/532710/), not `elfsign`, and that signature only covers loadable segments (which would require putting your custom section into one such segment if you wanted to use this).
Also, it requires static libraries (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9527322/5801661) for whys) and it doesn't look like a PKI but rather a simple sign/verify (i.e. no chain of trust).
For completeness, Linux also supports [IMA](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Integrity_Measurement_Architecture) for restricting execution but that's not based on cryptographic signatures at all (it's similar to a TPM measurement, so it's hash-based).

Comment: This is a great answer, thank! Is `elfsign` commonly used in the Linux world, meaning do distros typically ship with signed binaries and/or are package binaries typically signed?

Comment: @Cocowalla I would say the contrary: almost not used at all. Package managers generally use [signing mechanisms](https://wiki.debian.org/SecureApt) but only to verify the downloaded files are indeed valid/untempered. Once installed, these files have no signature.